# Showing that $X_{(1)}$ is sufficient for shifted exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

If the pdf of a random sample is $f(x)=e^{-(x-θ)}$ where $x \geq θ$,
Show that $T=X_{(1)}$ is a sufficient statistic for $θ$.

Can one show that $T$ is a sufficient statistic for $θ$ in the following manner?

Step 1: Find the pdf of $T$
$$f_{x_{(1)}}(x_{(1)})=ne^{-n(x_{(1)}-θ)} \quad x_{(1)} \geq θ$$

Step 2: Find the joint density of the random variables
$$f_θ(x_1,\ldots,x_
n)=e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-θ)} \quad x_i \geq θ $$

Step 3: Factor the joint density where we can extract the statistic in question
$$f_θ(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=e^{-(x_{(1)}-nθ)}\cdot e^{-\sum_{i=2}^n x_{(i)}}$$

Step 4: Manipulate the above expression so that one factor is the pdf of the sufficient statistic and the other a factor not depending on $θ$

$$f_θ(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=ne^{-n(x_{(1)}-θ)} \cdot \frac{1}{n} e^{-\sum_{i=2}^{n} (x_{(i)}-x_{(1)})}$$

Step 5: By the Neyman-Fisher factorization criterion $X_{(1)}$ is sufficient for $θ$.

The above solution was given in my class. However, I'm not so sure it constitutes a proper proof/explanation as it does not make use of the indicator function in the joint pdf. Does the fact that we can manipulate the joint pdf into a product containing the pdf of the sufficient statistic somehow circumvents the need to use the indicator function?

Comment: Similar Qs:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/506658/minimal-sufficient-statistics-for-2-parameter-exponential-distribution,

Comment: The title appears to have little to do with the question: where are the two parameters and what is "$\lambda$"?

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. I have edited the title.

Comment: Michael Hardy shows how to directly solve this problem. As a side note, intuitively we can reason about this that the distribution is one of an exponential distributed variable with known $\lambda = 1$ that is truncated at $\theta$. Any distribution (with fixed parameters) that is truncated like that has $X_{(1)}$ as sufficient statistic. There is no other information in the sample about the truncation point.

Answer (score 2):

$\require{cancel}$
$$
\xcancel{\vphantom{\sum^\sum_\sum} f_θ(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-θ)} \quad x_i \geq \theta}
$$
Instead of writing the joint density like that, do it like this:
$$
f_θ(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-θ)} \quad \theta \le x_{(1).}
$$
(And notice that you incorrectly used capital letters on the left side.)

That shows the way in which it depends on $x_{(1)}.$

Then you have
$$
f_\theta(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \underbrace{ \vphantom{\mathbf 1(\theta\le x_{(1)})} e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} } \,\, \underbrace{ e^{n\theta} \cdot \mathbf 1(\theta\le x_{(1)})}.
$$
where
$$
\mathbf 1(\theta\le x_{(1)}) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } \theta\le x_{(1)}, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$
Then you have one factor that depends on $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ only through the minimum $x_{(1)}$ and another that does not depend on $\theta.$

Comment: Thank you, Michael. The classroom solution was the factorization I showed at the end (where g was the pdf of the first order statistic and h the factor not depending on θ). The professor did not use the indicator function in the joint pdf. Is that solution flawed?

Comment: +1 The correct use of indicator functions is *crucial.* True, many people implicitly assume you know what the domain is and so (informally) they don't bother to write the indicator explicitly.  But it is exactly when working with these likelihoods that people run into trouble when they omit the indicators: we have (literally) hundreds of threads where that's the key issue.

Comment: @Wins94 : I would want to see the details of what the professor wrote and said before I could comment on that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's basically what I showed with the additional step of manipulating the result in step 2 so that it becomes the product of the pdf of the first order statistic and another factor that does not depend on θ (as shown in the last part). Should I edit the question to show those steps more clearly or is there another way on this platform I can show it so that you can see it (e.g. a separate discussion thread)?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have edited the question to show the solution provided by the professor as it does not alter the original intent of the question and does not affect the accepted solution you wrote.

Comment: @Wins94 : Maybe I'll get to this later today; right now several things are demanding my attention.

Comment: You can write $$
f_θ(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=
ne^{-n(x_{(1)}-θ)} \cdot \frac{1}{n} e^{-\sum_{i=2}^{n} (x_{(i)}-x_{(1)})} \cdot \mathbf 1(x_{(1)} \ge \theta)
$$ I would have either written it that way or written something like $$ f_\theta(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \begin{cases} \cdots\cdots\cdots & \text{if } x_{(1)} \ge \theta, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

Answer (score 0):

> Does the fact that we can manipulate the joint pdf into a product containing the pdf of the sufficient statistic somehow circumvents the need to use the indicator function?

It is no circumvention. You have indirectly these indicator functions as a condition for the function (highlighted in red below).

$$f_{x_{(1)}}(x_{(1)})=ne^{-n(x_{(1)}-θ)} \quad {\color{red} {x_{(1)} \geq θ}}$$

which you can read as short-handed for

$$f_{x_{(1)}}(x_{(1)})= \begin{cases}
ne^{-n(x_{(1)}-θ)} & \quad \text{if } { {x_{(1)} \geq θ}} \\
0 & \quad \text{if } { {x_{(1)} < θ}} 
\end{cases}$$

and can be written with an indicator function as

$$f_{x_{(1)}}(x_{(1)})=
ne^{-n(x_{(1)}-θ)} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{x_{(1)} \geq θ} 
$$

> Manipulate the above expression so that one factor is the pdf of the sufficient statistic and the other a factor not depending on θ

Note that the factorisation does not neccesarily need to result in a factor that is the pdf of the sufficient statistic. It can indeed always be written like that but it is not necessary. Having a look at the pdf of the potential sufficient statistic might help, but the factorisation can sometimes be easier when we do not force it to be in that particular way.

In your case the formula

$$f_θ(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=ne^{-n(x_{(1)}-θ)} \cdot \frac{1}{n} e^{-\sum_{i=2}^{n} (x_{(i)}-x_{(1)})}$$

is equal to

$$f_θ(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=e^{nθ} \cdot  e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{(i)}}$$

---

As a side note, intuitively we can reason that this is the distribution of an exponential distributed variable with known $\lambda = 1$ that is truncated at $\theta$.

In general, *any* distribution (with fixed parameters) that is truncated like that has $X_{(1)}$ as sufficient statistic. Other than the minimum value, there isn't any information in the sample about the truncation point.

Consider for example the following way to generate the data.

Compute uniform variables (representing quantiles)

$$Q_i \sim \mathcal{U}(q_t,1)$$

where $q_t = F(\theta)$ is the quantile where the truncation occurs.

And use the inverse transform to obtain $X_i$

$$X_i := F^{-1}(Q_i)$$

The latter transformation, defining the final distribution of the sample points, is irrelevant for the truncation point.  And so the distribution of the sample has no information about the truncation point.

Related is a description of the German tank problem [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/421795/164061). Describing why

> why the samples {1, 2, 10} and samples {8, 9, 10} have the same solution

Comment: I understand the indicator function is indirectly specified but as you pointed out, the final factorization is equivalent to one that is expressed as the total sum of the random variables. And we know that the sum of the random variables is not a sufficient statistic for a truncated exponential distribution with known rate parameter. So does this mean the solution is flawed?